# javascript:Chromeブラウザで「名前を付けて保存」ダイアログを表示し保存するようにしたい

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

現在下記ソースのような、ファイルダウンロードの実装しています。
そこで、Chromeブラウザで「名前を付けて保存」ダイアログを表示し保存するようにしたいのですが、下記ソースですとダイアログが出ずに保存されてしまいます。
方法のわかる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

また、自身で調査した観点としましては、
・javascriptで右クリック押下→Aキーを発火し、ダイアログを出す
・ファイル保存時に別タブで表示し、javascriptでCtrl + sを発火する

```js
var saveText = function(text, filename) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:text/plain,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    a.download = filename;
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, true, false, false,  0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

saveText('テキスト', 'ファイル名.txt');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家 StackOverflow にも同様の質問はいくつか見られますが、Chrome の設定を変える以外の方法は見つかりませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Chromeアプリであれば「[保存先の選択ダイアログを表示する](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry)」といった機能も用意されているようですが、お使いのテクニックはあくまで「ダウンロード」させるものですから、「ダウンロードしたファイルはダイアログなしで保存されることをユーザーが望んでいる」以上、それに従うのが正しいのではないでしょうか。

なお、Javascriptを使って**ブラウザに対する**キーボード・マウス操作のエミュレーションが行えないのはChromeの実装上の理由もあるでしょうが、セキュリティ上の観点からもできるとは思えません。

Comment: やはりそうですよね。丁寧な返答ありがとうございます。